# Invalid control character on readxml module Rocketbot

Tags: python, rpa

I have this error with Rocketbot module **"readXML"**. I run the command **"XML to Dict"** to convert my xml data to a dictionary but I get an exception **"Invalid control character at: line 1 column 95 (char 94)"**

What should I do? Please help

[image: Rocketbot error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable can have line breaks. You should try
this:
[image: this]

Answer (score 2):

As @Nicolas says you have to remove the line breaks in your variable

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try replace the "\n" character

With Set variable command write this: `"{xml}".replace("\n","")` or `"""{xml}""".replace("\n","")`

if not working try to replace \t character too

Answer (score 1):

Remember replace double-quotes to

```
{xml}['autorizacion']['comprobante'].replace("\n","").replace('"',"'")
```